# Preventing React to reaload map in a tabbed app

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am writing an react-inonic app using these version.

```
Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 5.2.2
```

I am kind of new to react and ionic.

The app is a multi tab app which contain a map using leaflet. Once that the map is loaded and I switch between tabs and I came back to the tab with the maps, this is reloaded all the time.

Afaiu react reload the component each time and this could be prevented by using the shouldComponentUpdate() life-cycle method. I've tried to implement it but it keep failing.

```
import React, { useState, shouldComponentUpdate } from "react";
import * as utils from './utilsHome';
import { CenterMap, DivLoading, HeaderHome, RenderMap, BottomHome } from "./componentsMap";

var startWatchID = "START";
const description = "blah blah";
let bcnumber = "25 bc";
let old_coords = {old_lat : "", old_lon: ""}

const Home = () => {
  
  let coords = usePosition({});
  let latitude = coords.latitude;
  let longitude = coords.longitude;
  let erorr = coords.error;

  var watchID = 0;

  let [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("START");
  let [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState("#006F16");

  function checkLatLon(lat, lon) {
    if (lat && lon) {
      return (
        <RenderMap latitude={lat} longitude={lon}>
          <CenterMap latitude={lat} longitude={lon}></CenterMap>
        </RenderMap>
      );
    } else {
      return <DivLoading />;
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log(nextProps, nextState);
    console.log(this.props, this.state);

    return false;  
  }

  function startToRide() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("UserRide") === "false") {
      utils.checkOldCoordsPresentInLocalStorage()
      old_coords["old_lat"] = latitude;
      old_coords["old_lon"] = longitude;
      utils.positionSaveData(old_coords);
      localStorage.setItem("UserRide", true.toString());
      setButtonColor("#D20D0D");
      setButtonText("STOP");
      watchID = onDeviceReady();
      localStorage.setItem("watchID", watchID.toString());
      startWatchID = "STOP";
      console.log("cerco per il cambio di colore");
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("UserRide", false.toString());
      setButtonColor("#006F16");
      setButtonText("START");
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(Number(localStorage.getItem("watchID")));
      localStorage.removeItem("watchID");
      utils.removeOldCoords()
      startWatchID = "START";
    }
  }
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        {/* Header components */}
        <HeaderHome description={description} bcnumber={bcnumber} />
        <div className="main_div_home_map">
          {
            /* This does conditional rendering 
            for map and loadingdiv       
        */
            checkLatLon(latitude, longitude)
          }
        </div>

        <div className="main_div_home_bottom">
          <div className="div_current_km">
            <p className="p_description_left">Kms</p>
            <p className="p_description_right">43</p>
          </div>

          <div className="div_co2_emissions">
            <p className="p_description_left">KG Co2 saved</p>
            <p className="p_description_right">1.5kg</p>
          </div>
          <div className="div_ride_button">
            <IonButton
              shape="round"
              onClick={startToRide}
              style={{ "--background": `${buttonColor}` }}
            >
              {buttonText}
            </IonButton>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div>
          <TemplateFooter />
        </div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

And this is the ApplicationRoutes which switch between tabs once the user click on the tabs

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthRoutes } from "../views/Auth";
import PrivateRoute from "../PrivateRoute";
import Shop from "../views/Dashboard/components/shop";
import Dashboard from "../views/Dashboard/components/home";
import Profile from "../views/Dashboard/components/profile";
import Offers from "../views/Dashboard/components/offers";

const ApplicationRoutes = () => {
    return (   
     // route can be omitted
        <Route>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/offers" component={Offers} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/shop" component={Shop} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                <Route path="/auth" component={AuthRoutes} />
                <Redirect to="/auth" from= "/" />
            </Switch>
        </Route>
    );
}
```

The error that I get in this case is this one

```
[react-scripts]   Line 48:47:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
[react-scripts]   46 |   }
[react-scripts]   47 | 
[react-scripts] > 48 |   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
```

If I shouldn't use the **shouldComponentUpdate** method, can you please drive me to the right way for this implementation ?